# Преобразование из float в int после умножения происходит с большой погрещностью

Tags: php, float, int

PHP 7.3.4 (нет возможности проверить на старый версиях, но думаю дело не в этом)

```
$f = 1.001 * 1000;
$i = (int)$f;
var_dump($f, $i);
```

**float(1001) int(1000)**

Почему после умножения float(1001) через (int) преобразуется как `1000`, а не `1001`?
Почему после 1001 * 1.0, как и после (float)1001 преобразуется нормально в `1001`?

P.S. Это же не логарифмы?
Мне казалось алгоритм преобразования в (int) преобразовать операнд в строку, а затем пройти каждый символ на соответствие 0-9, т.е. отбросить всё лишнее кроме цифр, а если это строка цифр то вернуть её же но числом.

Как оказалось алгоритм (int) ведёт себя совершенно по-другому неожиданным образом.

Comment: Потому что 1.001*1000 дает не 1001, а 1000.9999999999999. Увы, таковы ограничения двоичной архитектуры.

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Кстати, MySQL лишен этого "недостатка": `SELECT CAST(1.001 * 1000 as UNSIGNED);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прямое преобразование float в int работает путем отбрасывания дробной части. Из-за особенностей работы чисел с плавающей точкой умножение 1.001 на 1000 может дать результат не 1001 а 1000.999999

Для преобразования float в int желательно использовать функции округления.

Comment: Благодарю! round() помог.